# How does a user flag a question for review by more experienced users?

Tags: support, comments, answers, comment-flags

I have an answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564684/how-to-fix-error-updating-maven-project-unsupported-iclasspathentry-kind-4) that seems to be getting only (IMHO, of course) unconstructive comments.

For example, more and more of the comments seem to come from people who haven't read the answer -- obviously, maybe my answer isn't clear enough.

I have nowhere near the points/experience to modify the question -- and correctly so.

However, I'd like to be able to flag it so that someone else can decide whether or not there shouldn't be anymore comments.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: You can't just ignore the comments? They are just comments, after all, you received a lot of positive votes on your answer, which is the real validator of the quality of your answer.

Comment: @Martijn thanks, that bit of common sense makes the most sense.

Answer (score 3):

Place a bounty over the question.

Bounties tend to lure the experienced programmers, one main reason is they don't succumb to the daily rep cap of 200 plus it's always fun to win a bounty.

100 shiny points ought to attract some attention.

Anyway, as for comments first try to explain to the user who commented why he/she is wrong then they will hopefully remove their own comments. If this doesn't work, you can always flag such comments and if you see they won't go away and sure they are wrong you can flag your own post choosing "Other" and explaining the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that or ignore that from others..you can only flag that after getting the comments or the answers.

As New Comers can not directly post the comments.

Stackoverflow is already maintaining the structural paradigm in the repautation where specific activities are allowed to the user having specific amount of reputations.